# Preduals of von Neumann algebras consisting of vector functionals.

Tags: operator-theory

It is known that for a locally compact group $G$ the predual $M_{*}$ of the von Neumann algebra $M=vN(G)$ consists of vector functionals, i.e., if $\omega\in M_{*}$ then there exist vectors $\xi,\,\eta\in L^2(G)$ such that $\omega(x)=\langle{x\,\xi,\eta\rangle},\,\forall\,x\in M.$

So, a natural question is "which von Neumann algebras have this predual property?"

I found that hereditarily reflexive von Neumann algebras $M$ (i.e., every w*-closed subspace of $M$ is reflexive) and separably acting von Neumann algebras with a seperating vector (equivalently, $M^\prime$ has cyclic vector) have this property.

Does anyone else know something more? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First note that this property depends not only on the abstract von Neumann algebra (or $W^\ast$-algebra if you like), but the chosen representation.

The property that every element of the predual is a vector functional holds if the von Neumann algebra is in standard form (see Haagerup. The standard form of von Neumann algebras). The standard representation can be obtained as GNS representation for any faithful normal state (or weight). For example, the group von Neumann algebra $\mathrm{vN}(G)$ is acting standardly on $L^2(G)$ because this action is (unitarily equivalent to) the GNS representation with respect to the Haar weight.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the paper of Haagerup. You underline that, every reflexive von Neumann algebra is finite dimensional.  It is known that every von Neumann algebra is reflexive.

Comment: No, not every von Neumann algebra is reflexive. For example, $\ell^\infty$ is certainly not reflexive (and that's essentially the reason why no infinite-dimensional von Neumann algebra is reflexive).

Comment: I just figured you probably meant "reflexive" in the sense of Arveson, not as a Banach space. Sorry for the confusion, but you should probably clarify that in your question.

Comment: Yes, I mean "reflexive" due to Arveson. Sorry about this misunderstanding. Thanks again.

Comment: Every element of the predual or just the positive ones ?

Comment: I found that: if $\psi$ is a normal linear functional on $M$ then there is a positive linear functional $\phi$ on $M$ and a partial isometry $u\in M$ such that $\psi(x)=\phi(x u),\,x\in M.$

Comment: Yes, that's the polar decomposition for normal linear functionals. If you read up on Haagerup $L^p$ spaces, you'll see that this can really be interpreted as polar decomposition of an (unbounded) operator.

Comment: Btw, for your original question, I think for II$_1$ factors this property holds if and only if the coupling constant is finite, i.e., $M^\prime$ is finite. But you may want to double check.

Comment: 1) If $M$ is in standard position on $H$ does the same hold for $M_n(M)$ on $H^n$ ? and

Comment: 2) What about YMC*A ?  Nice experience ?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Yes. ;)

Comment: 1) On $H^n$ or on another Hilbert space (i.e. $M_n(H)$) ?

Comment: Good catch! Sorry, this was wrong. For example, $\mathbb C$ is in standard form on $\mathbb C$, but $M_n(\mathbb C)$ is not in standard form on $\mathbb C^n$. Indeed it should be $S^2_n\otimes H$, where $S^2_n$ denotes the Hilbert-Schmidt operators on $\mathbb C^n$ (i.e. $M_n(\mathbb C)$ with Hilbert-Schmidt inner product).

Comment: I was wondering when the property that "every element of the predual is vector functional" is stable under isomorphisms. For example, if the isomorphism comes from a unitary then we have an affirmative answer.  In general I am not sure.  Let me continue my thought. Voiculescu proved that $L(\mathbb{F}_2)$ is isomorphic to the algebra of 2x2 matirces over $L(\mathbb{F}_5).$ In this case, what happens? Is every element of the predual of $M_2(L(\mathbb{F}_5))$ a vector functional?

Comment: This property very much depends on the representation, i.e. is not stable under isomorphism. For example, $B(H)$ on $H$ does not have this property, but $B(H)$ on $B(S_2(H))$ does.